# How do I do this multi-dimensional array lookup with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this RGB image:

```
# 2D r, g and b channels
_r = np.array([[1,1],
               [0,0],
               [1,0]])

_g = np.array([[0,0],
               [1,1],
               [1,0]])

_b = np.array([[0,1],
               [1,0],
               [0,1]])

# Stack RGB into a single matrix
A = np.dstack((_r,_g,_b))
```

I'd like do use this image to index another array:

```
X = np.array(
  [[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

    [[.7,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]],


   [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0., .7,  0.]],

    [[ 0.,  0.,  .7],
     [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]]])
```

For each rgb triple in A, I'd like to grab three elements from X, which I can then add back to r, g and b, respectively.

```
lookup = X[A]  # this is wrong
A += lookup
```

I've tried a number of things, but can't get the right lookup

```
A += X[A]             # nope
A += X[ zip(A) ]      # nope
A += X[ zip(*A.T) ]   # nope
A += X[ zip(A.T) ].T  # nope
...
```

After the addition, A should be this:

```
array([[[ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 1. ,  0.7,  1. ]],

       [[ 0. ,  1. ,  1. ],
        [ 0.7,  1. ,  0. ]],

       [[ 1. ,  1. ,  0.7],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ]]])
```

**Edit**:
Here's a better description of the lookup I'm trying to do:

```
# For each rgb triple at (x,y) in A...
r, g, b = A[x,y]
dr, dg, db = X[r,g,b]
A[x,y] += (dr, dg, db)
```

Comment: Presumably, `lookup` has the same shape as `A` -- `(3, 2, 3)`. Can you post a formula or explanation for what `lookup[i,j,k]` equals?

Comment: your shapes just don't match... can you give an example what triplet from X you want to take for the first triplet in A? X has 8 triplets, but A has 6.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having a lot of trouble getting the shape right. Did my edit clarify what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is

```
A += X[_r, _g, _b]
```

Make sure that `A` is actually an array of floating-point numbers; otherwise you won't get the expected result.  (You can use `A.astype(float)` to convert an integer array to a floating-point array.)

If you don't have access to `_r`, `_g` and `_b` in your actual code, you can use `_r, _g, _b = A.transpose(2, 0, 1)` to extract the individual channels.

Comment: Hmm.. the `dsplit` call results in a misshaped array: it adds an extra length-1 dimension.